# AWS Glue - Crawl Json file and insert into Redshift

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Hi I am trying to use Aws Glue to load a S3 file into Redshift. When I try to crawl a Json file from my S3 bucket into a table it doesn't seem to work: the result is a table with a single array column as seen in the picture below. I have already tried using a Json Classifier with the path as "$[*]" but that doesnt seem to work either. Any ideas?

The structure of the Json file is the below:

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "andrew",
    "lastname": "johnson",
    "subject": "Mathematics",
    "mark": 49
  },
  {
    "firstname": "mary",
    "lastname": "james",
    "subject": "Physics",
    "mark": ""
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Peter",
    "lastname": "Lloyd",
    "subject": "Soc. Studies",
    "mark": 89
  }
]
```

The below is a screenshot for the resulted table, which is a single array column which cant be mapped to the table in Redshift:

[image]

Comment: Are you using the correct tool for this use case? Why use Glue over a Lambda function and the AWS SDK? You can write a Lambda funciton that uses the Amazon S3 API to read the content, parse the JSON and then use the Redshift Data Client API to perform database operations

Comment: Thanks for the question. Why would you use lambda over Glue? Only asking out of interest...

Comment: Typically Glue is used when the data set is so large - it will cause a Lambda to timeout. If it's a smaller data set, you can use Lambda/AWS SDK APIs to perform the data operations. To read data from an Amazon S3 bucket, you can use the Amazon S3 API to read the content and Redshift data client API to place the data into a Redshift database.

Comment: When you click the array in the datatype column, what does it show? It appears that the crawler is giving you a complex type in return, which is likely as expected. Often you will work with flattening out this complex type into something that is more consumable for the target.